# How list available BigQuery projects without parent?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am using Java client and I would like to list all projects that user has access to (as it appears in GCP console).

1. As documentation says it is recommended to use ResourceManager library instead of [BigQuery](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3397) ([BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html) library has no classes to retrieve projects - there is another one called [Bigquery](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Projects.html) (small q) that has some api for calling project, but documentation claims it is using ResourceManager underneath.
2. I tried using [v3 library](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list) version of ResourceManager but apparently it always requires the [parent id](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-resourcemanager/latest/com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3.ProjectsClient), but I don't want to give access for listing the folder above because in much more complicated architecture I would have to give access to all organisations and folders and prepare search of all projects. I would like only list projects that current user has access to.
3. There is also possibility to use same library but with [v1 api](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects) version which works like a charm... but it is deprecated and I am not sure how long it will be supported.
4. I don't want to use any other clients than Java.

Do you know solution using ResourceManager but not with parent or without granting too many privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the replacement for `list` is `search` method with empty query string:

```
ProjectsSettings projectsSettings = ProjectsSettings.newBuilder().build();
ProjectsClient projectsClient = ProjectsClient.create(projectsSettings);

ProjectsClient.SearchProjectsPagedResponse searchProjectsPagedResponse = projectsClient.searchProjects("");

for (Project project : searchProjectsPagedResponse.iterateAll()) {
        System.out.println(project.getDisplayName());
};
```